# How do you write your own custom measurement converters

Tags: java, jscience, jsr-275

How do you write your own custom converters and specify the conversion factor using javax.measure packages. (e.g. Pint [to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pint) gallons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know the "correct" way to do it, but the obvious way would be to follow the pattern of the [`NonSI` class](http://jscience.org/api/javax/measure/unit/NonSI.html); i.e. create your own class containing statics for each unit, with values based on the standard definitions for the non-SI units in terms of SI units.

Comment: But NonSI classes uses the following pattern to add new units public static final Unit<Length> YARD = nonSI(FOOT.times(3)); where nonSI is private method. Can you provide an example how to actually use it? I'm mostly interested if you can add a new unit and define it's symbol.

Comment: @FrEaKmAn - Obviously, you cannot dynamically define symbols for `static final` constants ... or any other Java symbols for that matter!  Or at least, not in a way that gives you any benefit.  Java is fundamentally a static language.  Source code symbols are resolved statically.  If you need dynamic "symbols", use a `Map`.

Comment: Thank you for Java lecture. Still this doesn't answer the question, where you mention that solution is obvious, but yet you are not able to add an example.

Comment: I am "able" to add examples, but I don't think it is necessary.  As for adding new symbols dynamically, that is hard - you need to use bytecode engineering or Java source code generation.  And it is ultimately pointless, IMO.  See explanation in comment above.